# What is importance of labelling a k8s resource and then applying selector on label in spec on same k8s resource?

Tags: kubernetes

Following are the example which I encountered on k8s website.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

**selector:
    run: my-nginx**
Not able to figure out what is the rationale behind labeling it in spec and then applying same selector on the spec definition.Found plenty of example but no explanation for them.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: load-balancer-example
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: load-balancer-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

**
 selector:

```
matchLabels:

  run: load-balancer-example**
```

Comment: Under the Hood, a deployment creates a ReplicaSet. One reason my be that it is easier for the Deployment-Controller to figure out which ReplicaSets and Pods belong to the Deployment. 

They could have used other approaches, like matching the name, but why when there is already a more simple and powerful mechanism .

Comment: really sounds crazy. Don't see the purpose of `matchLabels:  run: load-balancer-example` as the pods defined in the deployment should be selected automatically. The label should only make sense if the pods defined in this deployment should be referred from else where?  Great Question!!!!

Comment: but seems there is more to understand!!!!

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the fundamental design concepts of Kubernetes:

***Resources are linked by [labels and selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).***

Resources such as a Service or Deployment that must refer to other resources have a **selector** which defines a set of labels. These resources select all those resources (of a specific type) that have **labels** matching this selector.

For example, a Deployment with a selector of `a=b` refers to all Pods that happen to have the label `a=b`.

That's why in your Deployment specification, you have to define the same label (`run=load-balancer-example`) in the Pod template (`template` section) as in the selector of the Deployment. Because you want the Deployment to manage *these* Pods:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: load-balancer-example    # <<<<<----- must match
  replicas: 2
  template:  # <- you define a template for the Pods that will be created here
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: load-balancer-example  # <<<<------ must match
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

If you have any other Pods with the `run=load-balancer-example`, the Deployment will manage these too. On the other hand, if the labels in the Pod template of the Deployment specification were different from the selector, the Deployment wouldn't manage these Pods because their labels don't match the selector of the Deployment.

In your first example, the label definitions within the Service specification are unrelated. The first one (`labels`) is the label of the Service (you could omit it, if you want), the second one (`selector`) is the selector of the Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx  # <<<<<---- unrelated to the other 'run: my-nginx'
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my-nginx  # <<<<<---- unrelated to the other 'run: my-nginx'
```

However, the **selector *is* related to the labels of any Pods**. In particular, this Service will apply to all Pods that have the `run=my-nginx` label.

Comment: this should be gold

Comment: `the second one (selector) is the selector of the Service:` --> does this refer to only pods and not the service selecting itself?

Comment: @RedwinD Yes, it refers only to the Pods that the Service will route traffic to. Also see the specification of this field in the [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#servicespec-v1-core).

Comment: @weibeld, is not this bit redundant `matchLabels:  run: load-balancer-example` (in @prashant second example). as the pods defined in the deployment should be selected automatically. The label should only make sense if the pods defined in this deployment should be referred from else where?

Comment: Yes, it's redundant, but unfortunately it has to be like this. The Kubernetes API is modular. The object in `template` is a [PodTemplateSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podtemplatespec-v1-core) and it is used in other places of the Kubernetes API too. It's used for creating the Pods of the Deployment, and it must have a label so that these Pod definitions are self-contained. In earlier versions of the API, I think it was allowed to omit the selector of the Deployment, and it would just assume the labels from the template, but not anymore.

Comment: sorry bit late with response. But thx for clarification. That really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are there to group resources. Label selectors are there to target these grouped resources.

Depending on the resource, labels are used for one purpose or another. `Deployments` use labels to know what pods are their children (no label selectors are involved here), `Services` use labels to forward traffic to the backends (`Pods`). Network Policies use labels to allow or deny traffic, etc.

Why using labels? The most clear example is with services. Pods die all the time. When they are re-created, they have a different IP address. You can't rely on the IP address of a Pod, as it can change at any moment. So you create a service and target a group of pods, according their labels. Services don't die, unless you delete them. A pod that has been re-created with a different IP address has the same labels, so the service gets the new IP address of the pod as possible endpoint, and the traffic can still flow.